# os.path.isfile() returns false for existing Windows file

Tags: python

For some reason **os.path.isfile()** occasionally returns **false** for some existing Windows files. At first, I assumed that spaces in the filename were causing a problem, but other file paths with spaces worked fine. Here's copy from the Python console that illustrates this issue:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isfile("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\images\bing.ico")
False
>>> os.path.isfile("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\images\PinnedSiteLogo.contrast-black_scale-80.png")
True
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 9):

`\b` in a string means backspace. If you want actual backslashes in a string, they need to be escaped with more backslashes (`\\` instead of `\`), or you need to use a raw string (`r"..."` instead of `"..."`). For file paths, I'd recommend using forward slashes.

Comment: The following works:



`>>> os.path.isfile(r"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\images\bing.ico")
True`

However, the path is in a variable and I can't use r with variables.

Comment: @NemoXXX It shoulde be True. It's equal to `'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\images\\bing.ico`

Comment: @ skyline75489:  the path prefixed with r returns true, but I need a function, because the path is a variable and `os.path.normpath()` returns `'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\images\x08ing.ico'` which doesn't work because the lowercase b is \xAA.

Comment: @NemoXXX: Other than string literals in source code, most ways of getting a string won't process backslashes for escape sequences. If this string ultimately comes from a string literal somewhere, fix your string literals. If it doesn't, then find where the string is getting screwed up and fix it.

Comment: @user2357112: What is the Python function equivalent of the r prefix?

Comment: @NemoXXX: There is none. The "r" tag on a string literal is a tag saying "don't stick this in the blender". There's no function to unblend it; escape sequence processing isn't reversible. You need to find out what part of your code is sticking your strings in the blender and make it not do that.

Comment: My issue was that the ".exe" extension was missing on the path for an executable