# Missing path part \202

Tags: python, import, directory

when I try to load my data from a .txt file a part of the path gets missing. The code is

```
Uebergeord_Pfad = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Daten_Pfad="\Cu\20211124_16_37_Cu-St_CV_Hepes+Rh_pH8.txt"
data_file= Uebergeord_Pfad + Daten_Pfad
Rohdaten = np.loadtxt(data_file, delimiter=';', skiprows=1, usecols=(0,2))
```

an Error occurs

> ```
> raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
> ```
>
> OSError: C:\Users...\Messungen\Elektroden_CVs\Cu‚11124_16_37_Cu-St_CV_Hepes+Rh_pH8.txt
> not found.

the \202 part of the file name is missing. It makes no difference if im tiping the hole file name by myself or copy it. Somehow python changing \202 to an unknown letter. When I use an Test.txt file in the same directory it works properly.
Hope that there is an easy solution, so that I dont have to change all file names.

Best regards
Jonas

Comment: Prefix the path/string with `r` to make it a raw string, backslash is an escape character otherwise - `Daten_Pfad = r'...'`. You could also use double backslashes instead if you don't want to use raw strings - `Daten_Pfad = '\\...'`

Comment: Thanks the r'...' helped, now it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [os.path.isfile() returns false for existing Windows file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863318/os-path-isfile-returns-false-for-existing-windows-file)